# My Android App is not showing on the App Drawer

Tags: android, android-manifest, custom-url

I have an application with a single activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />

        <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="action1"/>
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="action2"/>
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="action3"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
</activity>
```

I need it to respond to `myscheme://` urls, and it is working in that regard. Unfortunately, it does not show in my App Drawer. If I remove the `android:scheme` lines, then it shows on the App Drawer, but then it no longer responds to `myscheme://` urls, obviously.

How can I fix this activity to make it both show on the app drawer and respond to the custom urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the `intent-filter` into two:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="action1"/>
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="action2"/>
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="action3"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I can only test this again on an actual device tomorrow, but a preliminary test on an emulator seems to indicate that this actually fixes it. Thanks! I'll mark your answer as accepted after I test this properly tomorrow.

Comment: That's correct, it is both showing on the launcher and accepting the custom URLs. I had thought that I had actually tried this particular combination before with no success, but it was probably something else. Thanks again!